# How to use timer in linux application layer

Tags: timer

I am trying to write a simple application on Linux in C. when a push button is press, a motor is started, after 20 seconds it is stop by a timer. apparently, I don't need a repeating timer, a one-shot timer is can do the job.

what I need to know is which timer api i can use set timeout and trigger my function when timer expires.

thanks a lot.

Comment: You've explained what you want, but SO users aren't going to write a bunch of code for you. You should attempt this on your own and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
For my case, using alarm if sufficient.basically,you need to define you StartMotor() and stopMotor() function and attach StopMotor function to  signal(SIGALRM, StopMotot);

```
RUN_DURATION      30  // 30 seconds
static bool MotorStarted = false;

static void StopMotor(int sig);

void  main(void){

while(1)
{
   if (IsPBPressed( )) //polling status of  push button.
   {

         if(!MotorStarted) //if motor is running, preceed startmotor,
         {                    // otherwise, ignore this subsequent request.

             MotorStarted = true;
              startMotor() 
             signal(SIGALRM, StopMotor);// start a timer. motor stop when the timer expires. 
             alarm(RUN_DURATION);              
         }
      }
   } //IsPBPressed( )
}
```